# How to forward with parameters

Tags: javascript, html

How can I forward with my `w` and `h` parameters?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="demo">Please maximize your browser then click OK.</p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">OK</button>
        <script>
            function myFunction()
            {
                var w=window.innerWidth;
                var h=window.innerHeight;
                x=document.getElementById("demo");
                x.innerHTML="Width: " + w + " Heigth: " + h;
            }
        </script>
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://80.169.28.12:3333/webRDP/start?v=192.168.1.13&u=domain%5C&pf=263&w="***!!w!!***"&h="***!!h!!***"">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript (not Java)? Are you trying to concatenate strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to redirect on click, remove the `<meta/>` tag, and add the following to the end of your function:

```
window.location.href = 'http://80.169.28.12:3333/webRDP/start?v=192.168.1.13&u=domain%5C&pf=263&w='+ w + '&h='+ h;
```